# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, numpy, testing, reshape, conv-neural-network

i have a dataset  and i used it for some training model including CNN model.... for thr CNN model i changed my data shape into 2D to 3D and 1D to 2D...

```
X_train=np.dstack(X_train).T
X_test=np.dstack(X_test).T
Y_train = np.reshape(Y_train,( Y_train.size,1))
Y_test = np.reshape(Y_test,( Y_test.size,1))
```

now i need to find testing,there i got struck  because already shape was changed... so in tesing the shape causing problem can anyone fix it

**Testing code**

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

for i in range(len(model)):
  print('Model',i)
  cm=confusion_matrix(Y_test,model[i].predict(X_test))
  TP=cm[0][0]
  TN=cm[1][1]
  FN=cm[1][0]
  FP=cm[0][1]

  print(cm)
  print('Testing Accuracy=',(TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FN+FP))
  print()
```

converting shape or any other ideas will be helpful

```
print(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape, Y_test.shape)
```

**shape of the values before**
(5273, 17) (5273,)
(586, 17) (586,)

**shape after reshape**
(5273, 17, 1) (5273, 1)
(586, 17, 1) (586, 1)

**Traceback**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-6a1c49606155> in <module>()
      4 for i in range(len(model)):
      5   print('Model',i)
----> 6   cm=confusion_matrix(Y_test,model[i].predict(X_test))
      7   TP=cm[0][0]
      8   TN=cm[1][1]

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

Comment: Can you tell the shape of Y_train and Y_test before and after reshaping

Comment: Why are you doing `model[i].predict` ? Can I know what model you're getting along with the output of it?

Comment: I just want to know what is inside model. It seems like you are not calling the model's predict function but a giving a mere float value. Just post your code on some hosted platform.. I'll be happy to debug

Comment: only i have done in previous models is like  ... i got the score() value from each models... and for testing i've listed them in loop @RaghavGupta